# com.android.camera Process NOT being Destroyed

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm trying to capture an image with the **android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE** and things seem to work fine, the only problem is that the process com.android.camera isn't being destroyed after returning and it is interfering with the running of the rest of the application.

So I'm wondering why it is not being destroyed and how I can destroy it once the capture is done? Thanks any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
    private OnClickListener buttonCaptureListener = new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"+Long.toHexString(System.currentTimeMillis())+".jpg";
        File file = new File(path);
        Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri );
        startActivityForResult(intent,SelectImagesActivity.REQUEST_CAPTURE);                
    }
};
```

Result handling:

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == SelectImagesActivity.REQUEST_CAPTURE){
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            // display image and etc.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's normal, android keeps apps running in the background as long as the system has enough resources for that. They will get killed eventually when the system needs memory. Should not be a problem in general. What exactly is the problem here - how does this interfere with your app?

Comment: After I capture/select images they are processed (meaning resized  and what not) and then uploaded what seems to be happening is the processing is being significantly slowed down with this process running, after I manually destroy it in the DDMS everything goes back to normal.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to reproduce the issue anymore. I didn't change anything, but the issue seems to be gone.

Answer (score 0):

I also think it is normal action that process is not destroyed immediately.
And I suggest below code for explicit meaning.
it is different that appending a extra data -('return data', true)- into the intent.

```
private OnClickListener buttonCaptureListener = new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        String file_name = Long.toHexString(System.currentTimeMillis())+".jpg";
        File file = new File(path , file_name);
        Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri );
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(intent,SelectImagesActivity.REQUEST_CAPTURE);                
    }
```